# Showing "JOptionPane.showMessageDialog" without stopping flow of execution

Tags: java, multithreading, dialog, jframe, execution

I'm currently working on a project that's getting more complex than I thought it would be originally. What I'm aiming to do right now is show a message dialog without halting the execution of the main thread in the program. Right now, I'm using:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "Received Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

But this pauses everything else in the main thread so it won't show multiple dialogs at a time, just on after the other. Could this m=be as simple as creating a new JFrame instead of using the JOptionPane?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html):

> JOptionPane creates JDialogs that are modal. To create a non-modal Dialog, you must use the JDialog class directly.

The link above shows some examples of creating dialog boxes.

---

One other option is to start the JOptionPane in its own thread something like this:

```
  Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello");
        }
    });
  t.start();
```

That way the main thread of your program continues even though the modal dialog is up.

Comment: OP: Be careful of the modality of the dialogs created by JOptionPane as well though, if you're popping up multiple dialogs then do you really want them to be modal?

Comment: Thanks iainmcgin. I really didn't think this through. Instead of using "JOptionPane.showMessageDialog" I just created a new JFrame that displayed the message.

Comment: Be careful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice

Comment: Firing a new thread did the trick. Seems to be the way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could just start a separate `Runnable` to display the dialog and handle the response.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                     JOptionPane op = new JOptionPane("Hi..",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                     JDialog dialog = op.createDialog("Break");
                     dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                     dialog.setModal(true);
                     dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);      
                     dialog.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    });
```